# How can I apply a custom css rule to small helping arrows that appears on column reordering in Kendo UI grid

Tags: css, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Does anyone knows which rule I have to override to change color and size of those small arrows?

[image]

Comment: we can't figure out until you post your code here or make fiddle

Comment: @Ismail Farooq KendoUI is not free. So a fiddle is not possible I guess. Perhaps with [http://dojo.telerik.com/](http://dojo.telerik.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without knowing what you want to put in it's place,  here this bit of css should help (from my investigations this is the only way to override this "image"):

```
 .k-grouping-dropclue{
            background-image:url("{YourImageHere}");
        }
```

This will override the default mapped sprite.

You will either need to make the new image fit the same dimensions or apply the additional css rules:

**width, height, background-size, background-repeat** to scale the background image correctly and provide the required size for the image. .

Please note by doing this you will then have to alter the positioning/margin if have a large background image.

here is a very simple demo: [grid with different drag handle](http://dojo.telerik.com/aLIHe)

this just uses one of the images provided to show what can be done.

Comment: Thanks David, you helped me a lot :)